# Can I use a list comprehension on a list of dictionaries if a key is missing?

Tags: python, dictionary, counter, list-comprehension

I want to count the number of times specific values appear in a list of dictionaries. However, I know that some of these dictionaries will not have the key. I do not know *which* though, because these are results from an API call.

As an example, this code works for `key1`, because all of the dictionaries have the key.

```
from collections import Counter
list_of_dicts = [
    {'key1': 'testing', 'key2': 'testing'},
    {'key1': 'prod', 'key2': 'testing'},
    {'key1': 'testing',},
    {'key1': 'prod',},
    {'key1': 'testing', 'key2': 'testing'},
    {'key1': 'testing',},
]

print Counter(r['key1'] for r in list_of_dicts)
```

I get a nice result of

```
Counter({'testing': 4, 'prod': 2})
```

However, if I change that last print to:

```
print Counter(r['key2'] for r in list_of_dicts)
```

It fails, because `key2` is missing in a couple of the dictionaries.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 11, in <module>
    print Counter(r['key2'] for r in list_of_dicts)
  File "h:\Anaconda\lib\collections.py", line 453, in __init__
    self.update(iterable, **kwds)
  File "h:\Anaconda\lib\collections.py", line 534, in update
    for elem in iterable:
  File "test.py", line 11, in <genexpr>
    print Counter(r['key2'] for r in list_of_dicts)
KeyError: 'key2'
```

How can I use a list comprehension to count the values of `key2` and not fail if a dictionary doesn't contain the key?

Comment: What should it use if the key doesn't exist?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can explicitly check if `key2` is in a dictionary:

```
Counter(r['key2'] for r in list_of_dicts if 'key2' in r)
```

Answer (score 3):

`get` lets you specify a default value to return if the key isn't present.  thus:

```
In [186]: Counter(r.get('key2',None) for r in list_of_dicts)
Out[186]: Counter({'testing': 3, None: 3})
```

Where the `None` entry tells us how many dictionaries were missing this value.  It might be nice to know that.  If you don't care, it probably doesn't matter much whether you use this or the `if` clause.