# Obtaining a numpy array from an array acting on a dictionary

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary

I want to have an array act on a dictionary and return me the corresponding values. Rather than loop through it would be nice to do that in a pythonic way ie something like

`results[:] = dict[np_vec[:]]`

That doesn't work though, I was hoping maybe there is a method I'm not aware of?

In this case the `np_vec` has integers which correspond to a key in the dict, while the values are tuples and I would want to have a list of them in `results`.

Answer (score 1):

The most straight forward Pythonic (i.e. uses good Python syntax) method is

```
results = [dict[value] for value in np_vec]
```

This needs refinement if `dict` might not have `value`.

[Can I use a list comprehension on a list of dictionaries if a key is missing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34710571/can-i-use-a-list-comprehension-on-a-list-of-dictionaries-if-a-key-is-missing)

But perhaps you are hoping for something that passes as a vectorized `numpy` expression.  The sticking point is that a dictionary will only access one key at a time

Another possibility is to use `dict.keys()` to get a list of keys, and use numpy methods to match `np_vec` with this list.  No guarantee that this will be faster.

`in1d` doc

```
> in1d(a, b) is roughly equivalent to np.array([item in b for item in a]).
```

I'm thinking of something like (but details may be off)

```
 keys = dict.keys()
 values = dict.values()    
 mask = np.in1d(dict.keys(), np_vec)
 result = values[mask]
```

---

Working code using arrays:

A dictionary with numeric keys, tuple values:

```
In [302]: adict={k:v for k,v in zip([0,1,2,3,4,5],[(0,1),(1,2),(2,3),(3,4),(4,5)])}
In [303]: adict
Out[303]: {0: (0, 1), 1: (1, 2), 2: (2, 3), 3: (3, 4), 4: (4, 5)}
```

Array of keys we want to fetch

```
In [304]: npvec=np.arange(4)
```

Lists from dictionary:

```
In [305]: keys=list(adict.keys())
In [308]: values=list(adict.values())
In [309]: values
Out[309]: [(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5)]
```

`mask` - keys we want to pull

```
In [310]: mask=np.in1d(keys,npvec)
In [311]: mask
Out[311]: array([ True,  True,  True,  True, False], dtype=bool)
```

To apply the `mask` in one step, we have to use an array; `keys[mask]` does not work:

```
In [313]: np.array(keys)[mask]
Out[313]: array([0, 1, 2, 3])
```

The same would work if `values` were simple numbers, but they are tuples.

```
In [314]: np.array(values)[mask]
Out[314]: 
array([[0, 1],
       [1, 2],
       [2, 3],
       [3, 4]])
```

We could turn that 2d array back into a list of tuples.

But to preserve tuples (or other general Python object values), we have to do something more complicated, e.g.

```
In [315]: varray=np.empty(len(values),dtype=object)
In [317]: for i in range(5):varray[i]=values[i]
In [318]: varray
Out[318]: array([(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5)], dtype=object)
```

Now we can apply the `mask` and get the right set of values.

```
In [319]: varray[mask]
Out[319]: array([(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4)], dtype=object)
```

Contrast that with the simple list comprehension solution:

```
In [321]: [adict[v] for v in npvec]
Out[321]: [(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4)]
```

Sometimes trying to be more Pythonic, err numpy-onic, just isn't worth the extra work.